# Size dependent on scroll

Tags: html, scroll

I want to know how to make a element opacity dependent on the scroll position of the page. For example, if my element is in the middle of the page, that element becomes more and more opaque, as the user scrolls to the middle.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to achieve this using css only or is javascript good too?

Comment: Javascript is definitely alright too! Jquery is preferred though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code, where ref1 and ref2 are the top and bottom position in window coordinates where the element became fully opaque, and fadeSize is the scroll amount needed to make the element fully invisible. The code automatically handles all elements with the class "ScrollFade":

```js
$(function() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        var ref1 = $(window).height() * 0.4;
        var ref2 = $(window).height() * 0.6;
        var fadeSize = 100;
        $('.ScrollFade').each(function() {
            var $elem = $(this);
            var h = $elem.height();
            var top = $elem.offset().top - window.scrollY;
            var bottom = top + h;
            var opacity;
            if (top < ref1 && bottom > ref2 || ref1 < top && top < ref2 || ref1 < bottom && bottom < ref2) {
                opacity = 1;
            } else if (top > ref2) {
                opacity = 1 - (top - ref2) / fadeSize;
            } else if (bottom < ref1) {
                opacity = 1 - (ref1 - bottom) / fadeSize;
            }
            opacity = Math.min(Math.max(0, opacity), 1);
            $elem.css('opacity', opacity);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 50cm;
    position: relative;
}

#myElem {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20cm;
    height: 3cm;
    width: 5cm;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElem" class="ScrollFade">Lorem ipsum</div>
```